# How to unit test a method that uses a dependency to copy an object?

Tags: unit-testing

Consider the following code (in C# but it could be any other language):

```
public interface IObjectCopier
{
    void Copy<T>(T source, T target);
}

public class Model
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    private readonly IObjectCopier _objectCopier;

    public ViewModel(IObjectCopier objectCopier)
    {
        _objectCopier = objectCopier;
    }

    public Model ViewBindData { get; set; }

    public void Load(Model model)
    {
        _objectCopier.Copy(model, ViewBindData);
    }
}
```

How do I construct a unit test for the Load method? If I mock IObjectCopier then I need to supply a mock implementation of the Copy method. In this example it is trivial but in a real world scenario Model can be large with sub models and the mocking exercise feel like it is just copying what the IObjectCopier implementation does.

The problem is simplified if I could change the Copy method to the following:

```
T Copy<T>(T source);
```

As in this case the mock setup is drastically simplified. The problem is that there are view bindings to the Model object and I cannot simply destroy and re-create the object.

Is there an elegant way to get around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using mocks, then the only thing you care about is that the copier is invoked with the 2 parameters.

So in some sort of pseudo code

```
test "populates model from view data" {
   objectCopiermock = mock(IObjectCopier)
   model = new Model() //create empty or use a TestDataBuilder
   viewBindData = new viewBindData() //create empty or use a TestDataBuilder
   viewModel = new ViewModel(objectCopiermock)
   viewModel.viewBindData(viewBindData)

   viewModel.Load(model)

   verifyMock(objectCopiermock).copy(model, viewBindData) 
}
```

The important thing with mocks is to verify the interactions, and not the values inside model or viewBindData.

If this is confused, don't panic! (tm) - and I would suggest you to read a bit about the difference between the [**London and Chicaco/Detroit schools of TDD**](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=detroit+vs+london+tdd+school&t=ffsb&ia=qa)

Comment: Of course! I am a little rusty. I should only care that the copier is invoked. Thanks.